# JooQ Ant Codegeneration not working

Tags: java, sql, ant, code-generation, jooq

Following the example given at http://www.jooq.org/doc/2.4/manual/META/Configuration/#N10607 on how to run the jooq code-generation I ran into the problem that the build fails with the message:

`codegen.xml:7: taskdef class org.jooq.util.GenerationTask cannot be found`

For a reference, here is codegen.xml

```
<project name="..." default="generate-test-classes"
basedir=".">
<property name="path.to.jooq.distribution" value="${basedir}/libs"/>
<property name="path.to.mysql.driver" value="${basedir}/libs"/>
<property name="mysql.driver" value="mysqlcon"/>
<!-- Task definition -->
<taskdef name="generate-classes" classname="org.jooq.util.GenerationTask">
    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${path.to.jooq.distribution}">
            <include name="jooq.jar" />
            <include name="jooqmeta.jar" />
            <include name="jooqcodegen.jar" />
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="${path.to.mysql.driver}">
            <include name="${mysql.driver}.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>

<!-- Run the code generation task -->
<target name="generate-test-classes">
    <generate-classes jdbcurl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crawler"
        jdbcuser="..." jdbcpassword="..." generatordatabaseinputschema="..."
        generatortargetpackage="model.persistence.jooq"
        generatortargetdirectory="${basedir}/src" />
</target>
</project>
```

I triple checked the definition of the classpath and every file listed exists under the given location. So what would be the problem? Am I missing something? Do I need to configure ant somewhere to recognize the task?

Since I already checked [ant: failed to create task or type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969474/ant-failed-to-create-task-or-type), I tried to move the taskdef inside the target, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ant task was an example implementation in jOOQ 2.x. It has been deprecated a long time ago and removed from jOOQ 3.0:

- http://www.jooq.org/notes.php?version=3.0
- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/1118
- http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.1/manual/code-generation/codegen-configuration/#N12E23

The version of the manual that you've linked is quite outdated.