# failed to create task or type translate-classpath

Tags: java, classpath

This is the first time I've ever seen this error and I don't know how to fix it at all. The error is

```
run:
C:\Users\matt\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:48: Problem: failed to create task or type translate-classpath
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

And my code is

```
package xj3dtest;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import static java.lang.Boolean.TRUE;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.*;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Xj3DTest extends JFrame {

    public Xj3DTest(String title) {

        super(title);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Setup browser parameters
        HashMap requestedParameters=new HashMap();
        requestedParameters.put("Antialiased",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("TextureQuality","medium");
        requestedParameters.put("PrimitiveQuality","medium");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_InterfaceType","SWING");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_NavbarShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_NavbarPosition","TOP");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_LocationShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_LocationPosition","TOP");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_LocationReadOnly",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_ShowConsole",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_OpenButtonShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_ReloadButtonShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_StatusBarShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_FPSShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_ContentDirectory","CurrentDirectory");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_AntialiasingQuality","low");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_Culling_Mode", "frustum");

        System.setProperty("x3d.sai.factory.class", "org.xj3d.ui.awt.browser.ogl.X3DOGLBrowserFactoryImpl");
        BrowserFactory.setBrowserFactoryImpl(
                new org.web3d.ogl.browser.X3DOGLBrowserFactoryImpl()
        );
        X3DComponent x3dComponent = BrowserFactory.createX3DComponent(requestedParameters);

        Browser browser = x3dComponent.getBrowser();

        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        cp.add((javax.swing.JPanel)x3dComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        X3DScene scene = browser.createX3DFromURL(new String[] {"test.x3d"});

        browser.replaceWorld(scene);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Xj3DTest frame = new Xj3DTest("Xj3D test");
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And in the `run.xml` file, it is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="{0} (run)" default="run" basedir=".">
    <target name="run">        
        <translate-classpath classpath="${classpath}" targetProperty="classpath-translated" />
        <property name="run.jvmargs" value="" />
        <property name="work.dir" value="${basedir}"/>
        <property name="application.args" value="" />
        <property name="java.failonerror" value="true"/>
        <java classpath="${classpath-translated}" classname="${classname}" dir="${work.dir}" jvm="${platform.java}" fork="true" failonerror="${java.failonerror}">
            <jvmarg value="-Dfile.encoding=${encoding}"/>
            <redirector inputencoding="${encoding}" outputencoding="${encoding}" errorencoding="${encoding}"/>
            <jvmarg line="${run.jvmargs}" />
            <arg line="${application.args}" />
            <syspropertyset>
                <propertyref prefix="run-sys-prop."/>
                <mapper from="run-sys-prop.*" to="*" type="glob"/>
            </syspropertyset>
        </java>
    </target>
</project>
```

And line 48 is `<translate-classpath classpath="${classpath}" targetProperty="classpath-translated" />` and the `Jars` I have are

```
gluegen-rt
gluegen-rt-natives-linux-amd64
gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64
gluegen-rt-natives-windows-i586
j3d-core-1.3.1
jhall
joal
joal-natives-linux-amd64
joal-natives-windows-amd64
joal-natives-windows-i586
jogl-all
jogl-all-natives-linux-amd64
jogl-all-natives-windows-amd64
jogl-all-natives-windows-i586
xj3d.browser_2.1.0-nps
xj3d.cadfilter_2.1.0-nps
xj3d-2.1-3rdparty-nps
xj3d-2.1-nps
xj3d-core
xj3d-runtime
xj3d-script-base
```

I've linked the project to the library that contains all the `Jars` by using the line `-Xmx450M -Djava.library.path="C:\Users\matt\Documents\NetBeansProjects\jar"` in the VM Options in the project properties and I've added the library to the libraries option.

I really don't know how to solve the problem.

**Edit**

It's still not fixed.

Comment: I have not used Ant myself but perhaps these can be of help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407637/apache-ant-does-not-recognize-for-task-macro-although-i-have-added-ant-contri and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969474/ant-failed-to-create-task-or-type

Comment: @user3493289 Thanks. But those two answers said to change the `taskdef` which isn't in my run.xml and those two also said that the problems were in the build.xml where mine is in the run.xml

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but with a brand new project. Uninstalling and reinstalling NetBeans fixed it for me. The same program that had been giving errors compiled and ran successfully so I suspect it is IDE related rather than code related.

Answer (score 0):

I started a new project in netbeans and created the same classes and it worked. It has nothing to do with code. It is a bug with netbeans.